# how to turn internet connection (GPRS/EDGE/3G) on/off

Tags: android

I am trying to turn off the internet connectivity thru android app like GPRS/EDGE/3G. When needed I need to turn on the same. But I could not find how to do that.

What is the API which supports this. Please help me.

Comment: This project does what you want to do. Review code of this project: http://code.google.com/p/apndroid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sarwar Erfan

"This project does what you want to do. Review code of this project: code.google.com/p/apndroid – Sarwar Erfan"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the phone on airline mode? It should stop all incoming and outgoing data, phone calls but still let the user play around with data/applications already on the phone.

You can check the settings that deal with putting a phone on airline mode [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#AIRPLANE_MODE_ON).

HTH,
Sriram

Comment: No. I want some API to turn them on & off. I need to selectively choose the network and turn them on/off.

Comment: @Jai: Check out wifi_on in the same link as above.