# Turn on the network provider

Tags: android

Is it possible to turn on the phone radios (3G/Data connection) from an android application, without navigating to the settings page?
How?

Comment: From inside your application ( by programming)  or you just need an app, to do it easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is similar to: [how to turn internet connection (GPRS/EDGE/3G) on/off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850425/how-to-turn-internet-connection-gprs-edge-3g-on-off)

Have a look at the project mentioned in the answer: http://code.google.com/p/apndroid/