# How to check Use network-provided values checkbox programatically in android

Tags: android, systemtime

it is possible to check use network provided values chekbox pro-grammatically?I want to check that checkbox using code.How can I do it?

[image: I want to check marked checkbox using programme]

Comment: how??can you write that code here??

Comment: ok I will write now for you

Comment: check out my answer....... but it will work for 2.3 above....... if needs anything then please ask me

Comment: After your test please accept and +1 , it will boost me up

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee thanx for yr answer..but it seems that your code is check mobile data(GPRS) coz I have used this code for it.

Comment: so what do you want? can you elaborate ?

Comment: I want to check red mark checkbox and for your information you can see it in settings->date and time of device.How can I check this checkbox?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44768/discussion-between-nitish-patel-and-satyaki-mukherjee)

Comment: ok let's try to do this.......

Comment: You can not do this in such a way. I have develop a code, which will auto redirect to your given screen. Otherwise I think no feasible solution found.

Comment: will you please write down that code..

Comment: please see my edited answer, it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
YourActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));
```

It is not possible to enable it directly from your code. This code will help you to automatically go to that screen.You can then check or uncheck it and then return back to the your screen.

Answer (score 2):

android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME)

0 - not checked
1 - checked

Answer Credits Matthias Robbers

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ConnectionDetector {

        private Context _context;

        public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
            this._context = context;
        }

        /**
         * Checking for all possible internet providers
         * **/
        public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
            ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
              if (connectivity != null)
              {
                  NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
                  if (info != null)
                      for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                          if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                          {
                              return true;
                          }

              }
              return false;
        }
    }
```

This question is similar to:
[how to turn internet connection (GPRS/EDGE/3G) on/off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850425/how-to-turn-internet-connection-gprs-edge-3g-on-off)

Have a look at the project mentioned in the answer:[http://code.google.com/p/apndroid/](https://code.google.com/p/apndroid/)